# Angular 4: Not able to click drop down menu

Tags: angular

I hope this a valid question. If not please suggest how I can improve.

I finally able to create a sample project in Angular first time and uploaded in stackblitz. Actually I have other questions, but before that I am not sure why I am not able to click on dropdown menu in stackblitz. I can click on "Alert" and "Configuration" in the navbar in my local machine. Can anyone please help me on this. I have not much knowledge about how stackblitz works. If the below stackblitz doesn't work, please let me know. This is first time I am developing an Angular and first time I am creating a project in any online editor.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-1b3r3r-3mhncg

Comment: According to your profile, you have been a member of SO for a little over 6 years. Are you *still* unsure what is on/off-topic on the site? And, no, your stackblitz isn't working.

Comment: Yes, I have been  member since a while. As I said I am new in Angular and GIT in my project. Earlier I did have some code github, but at that time I used to only upload from local computer. But now it is like all command line. I always used SVN. I read some article about creating stackblitz from github and tried that first time.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed for few menu's (Alert, Configuration and burger menu): https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-1b3r3r-axdv2u

Step 01: Toggling show/hide menu

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" ... (click)="showMenu=!showMenu;">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse" [class.collapse]="!showMenu">
...
</div>
```

Step 02: Hide menu while use click anywhere in the document.
import {Component, OnInit, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
...

```
    @HostListener('document: click', ['$event'])
    onClick(ev) {
      if(ev.target.classList.contains("navbar-toggler")) { 
        this.reset(true, false, false);
      }
      if(ev.target.classList.contains("navbar-alert")) { 
        this.reset(false, true, false);
      }
      if(ev.target.classList.contains("navbar-config")) { 
        this.reset(false, false, true);
      }
    }

    reset(showMenu, shoeAlert, showConfig) {
      this.showMenu = showMenu;
      this.showAlert = shoeAlert;
      this.showConfig = showConfig;
    }
```

Comment: Truly appreciate! One thing, do we have to write code manually to toggle? I thought it would be taken care by Bootstrap/Angular. And I don't have code in my local, bu tit is working fine in my local.

Comment: I though are you using only bootstrap css. The bootstrap.angular dependency is missing. In stackblitz Expand Dependency above the setting and type the npm package name to install.